# Separating numeric values using the cut function within ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, cut

I am working with some Mollusk growth data (10 specimen specifically) and am trying to make a plot in ggplot2. I would like half the points on a scatterplot to be one color and the other half a different color. I am trying to split the two numeric ranges and assign them a color using the cut() function.

```
#converts x & y into numeric modes
merged_subsets_2%>%
  mutate(k = as.numeric(k))
merged_subsets_2%>%
  mutate(accepted_species = as.numeric(accepted_species))

#plots data and colors two ranges
viz_moss_data <- ggplot(merged_subsets_2, aes(x=accepted_species,y=k))+
  geom_point(aes(colour = cut(k, c(0.014,0.03,2.83))),size = 5)+
  scale_color_manual(name = "k",values = c("(0.014,0.03]" = "blue","(0.03,2.83]" = "red"),labels = c("High d13C","Low d13C"))+
  labs(title = "'K' von Bertalanffy growth coefficient vs Mollusk Species",subtitle = "Mollusk Specimen sourced from Moss et al. 2016",y= "k growth coefficient",x="Mollusk Species (Low to High d13C)", color="New legend label")

#reorders x axis
viz_moss_data + scale_x_discrete(limits=c("edulis","islandica","islandica","demissa","nobilis","mactroides","casta","viridis","dentifer","japonicum"))
```

The geom_point() area contains my cut function. When I run the code I get an error saying "Error in cut.default(k, c(0.014, 0.03, 2.83)) : 'x' must be numeric". The first line of code shows me clearly changing the x axis data to a numeric format.

Can you spot another issue that might be coming up with the error?

Answer (score 0):

In the OP's post, the 'k' is converted, but it is not updated in the original data.  We can assign (`<-`) the output back to the original data

```
library(dplyr)
merged_subsets_2 <- merged_subsets_2%>%
             mutate(k = as.numeric(k), 
                    accepted_species = as.numeric(accepted_species))
```

Or another option is `%<>%` operator from `magrittr`

```
library(magrittr)
merged_subsets_2%<>%
             mutate(k = as.numeric(k),
                    accepted_species = as.numeric(accepted_species))
```